# Character shifts [Java]

Tags: java, string, methods, logic, character

I need to know the logic behind this java question:

> Identify the character shifts to for the following entered text to
>   become `"aptech"` (only Aptech will be entered with character shifts).

Input: `"bqufdi"`
Output: `"Character Shift = 1"`

Does anyone help me out on this java question, please? Thanks.

Comment: The first letter of the input is `b`. That is 1 character on from the `a` of `aptech`. `'b'-'a' == 1`

Comment: thanks andrew now it solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s = "aptech";
String in = "bqufdi";
```

You could write a simple `for` statement like

```
for(int i = 0; i < in.length(); ++i)    
    System.out.print(in.charAt(i) - s.charAt(i)); // shift for each letter
```

That outputs `111111` and means that all letters in `"bqufdi"` are shifted to one position on the right.